# Format string produced by a loop

Tags: string, matlab, loops, text

What i want to do is get the string from edit `a` and then modify it through a `for` loop. I managed to do this but i have trouble displaying the answer in text `b`. I managed to find the command `fprintf`, but i don't understand how to apply it to my script.

```
function jakob_translate

figure('name','Jakob translate','color',[0.5  0.5 0.9]);  % some things to work with
a=uicontrol('style','edit','position',[85 250 400 30]);
d=uicontrol('style','pushbutton','position',[200 200 50 40],'string','översätt','callback',@rovarspraket);
b=uicontrol('style','text','position',[85 100 400 60]);

function rovarspraket (~,~)   % this function should read the input string from a, and keep each vocal as it is, but every consonant should be modified to 'consonant o consonant'.

    c=get(a,'string'); %getting data that I can use to make a for loop.
    e=length(c);
    for i=1:e
        text{i}=c(i:i);
    end

    for i=1:e
  text(i:i) ;

  if text{i}=='a'     % If statement to do what i want the function to do, keep vocals and modify consonants.
         text{i}='a';
     elseif text{i}=='e'
         text{i}='e';
     elseif text{i}=='y'
         text{i}='y';
     elseif text{i}=='u'
         text{i}='u';
     elseif text{i}=='i'
         text{i}='i';
     elseif text{i}=='o'
         text{i}='o';
     elseif text{i}=='å'
         text{i}='å';
     elseif text{i}=='ä'
         text{i}='ä';
     elseif text{i}=='ö'
         text{i}='ö';
     else 
         text{i}=[text{i} 'o' text{i}];
  end

     k=text;


end
     set(b,'string',k)   %set the string in b to display the modified string from a.
   end
end
```

Comment: by typing in `a` `'sedes'` I am obtaining in `b` `['sos';'e';'dod';'e';'sos']` (a column). What should you get?

Comment: It isn't exactly clear to me what you want to achieve. Could you add comments to your code to where and what you are doing?

Comment: I edited the code by making some comments in it. The code works, but I would like to display the answear in b as a single line string. As it is now, each letter is in a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answear!

it was the command

cell2mat that i was searching for!

just added the line

```
k=cell2mat(k)
```

on the line before

```
set(b,'string',k)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great application for a regular expression.  You want to replace every character that's not a member of the set of vowels with itself plus "o" plus itself:

The whole translation function can look like this:

```
c=get(a,'string'); %getting data that I can use to make a for loop.
translated = regexprep(c, '([^aeiouåäö])', '$1o$1');
set(b, 'string', translated);
```

Explanation: `[abcde]` would match any single letter in the list.  Adding the `^` negates the set, meaning it matches any letter NOT in the set.  Finally the parentheses "capture" the value of that letter and make it available to use in the replacement text as `$1`.